# How to search in website and get the next args?

Tags: javascript

For example this website: https://servers.fivem.net/#/servers/detail/51.38.98.86:30120

This website presents the number of players in the server.
How can I get the next arguments after "Players:" and put it in var?

Thank you for help.

Comment: do you need a CSS selector or what?

Comment: I guess so. I'm using JS.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```js
var playerCount = $("div.player-list ul").find("li").length;

console.log(playerCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// EXAMPLE HTML PAGE WITH SAME STRUCTURE

<div class="player-list">
  <ul>
    <li>player 1</li>
    <li>player 2</li>
    <li>player 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var someVar =  document.getElementsByClassName('desc')[0]
    .children[3]
    .textContent
    .split(':')[1]
    .trim('')
```

I don't like what are you doing, but try it :)